# Catch to only allow 2 input types within a for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment when this runs, the user can ask for a vowel or consonant by entering 'c' or 'v' anything thing else will throw a error.

How would I edit the code as to add a catch with what I assumed would be isisntance possibly?

```
for i in range(9):
    x = input("letter("+str(i+1)+"), Would you like a consonant (c) or a vowel (v)? :")
    if x == 'c':
        randomLetters += getConsonant()
        print(randomLetters)
    elif x == 'v':
        randomLetters += getVowel()
        print(randomLetters)
return (randomLetters)
```

Finished code for people interested, thanks for answers helped me work through it.

```
for i in range(9):
    msg = "letter("+str(i+1)+"/9), Would you like a consonant (c) or a vowel (v)? :"
    x = input(msg)
    while x != "c" and x != "v":
        print("put a damn c or v in")
        x = input(msg)
    if x == 'c':
        randomLetters += getConsonant()
        print(randomLetters)
    elif x == 'v':
        randomLetters += getVowel()
        print(randomLetters)
return (randomLetters)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. It's moving on to the next letter, irrespective of the input.
2. It's not handling the case when the input is not `"c"` or `"v"`.
3. It's not giving any msg to the user about the invalid input.

What I have done here:
On each iteration in the for loop, we go into an infinite loop, which continues until valid input is given.

1. Take the first input, and enter the while loop.
2. For valid input, after the "valid" handling, we `break` the inf loop, and move to the next letter.
3. For invalid input, we display an error msg, take the input again, and go to 2.

The "fixed" version <sup>1</sup>:

```
for i in range(1,10): # no need for the +1 in string.
    msg = "letter({0}), Would you like a (c)onsonant or a (v)owel? : ".format(i)
    x = input(msg) # raw_input(msg)
    while True: # infinite loop
        if x == 'c':
            randomLetters += getConsonant()
            print(randomLetters)
            break
        elif x == 'v':
            randomLetters += getVowel()
            print(randomLetters)
            break
        else: # x not in ['c','v']
            print('Invalid input, {0} is not valid'.format(x))
            x = input(msg) # get new input and repeat checks
return (randomLetters)
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>with some extra tweaks</sub>

Comment: I accepted quickly mainly for the idea of what you did, i took it and made some alterations to help me,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python 3.x, `input()` returns a string.
So:

```
for i in range(9):
    x = input("letter("+str(i+1)+"), Would you like a consonant (c) or a vowel (v)? :")
    if not x.isalpha(): raise TypeError('x can only have be a string')
    if x == 'c':
        randomLetters += getConsonant()
        print(randomLetters)
    elif x == 'v':
        randomLetters += getVowel()
        print(randomLetters)
return (randomLetters)
```

If you only want the input to be 'c' or 'v':

```
for i in range(9):
    while not x in ('c', 'v'):
        x = input("letter("+str(i+1)+"), Would you like a consonant (c) or a vowel (v)? :")
    if x == 'c':
        randomLetters += getConsonant()
        print(randomLetters)
    elif x == 'v':
        randomLetters += getVowel()
        print(randomLetters)
return (randomLetters)
```

Comment: Hmm i can't really get this to work, as when i enter a string of not c or v, it jus treturns a red error instead of asking the user to select another letter for the same 'i'

Comment: @jack You did not specify that you wanted it to continue to loop; you said you wanted to catch if it wasn't proper input. Changed the second code to reflect it.